# Using LINQ to SQL to query a word started with something within string

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-sql

> I'd take both C# or VB.NET suggestion.

I'm using LINQ to SQL to query some data.

Here's my Employees table colummns:

-FirstName (or givename i.e. John)
-LastName (has middle name and family name seperated by space i.e. Mac Tenny

Some people have middle name and some don't. Here's some sample data.

-FirstName LastName

- John Mac Tenny (with middle name "Mac")
- Mike Mika (no middle name)
- Sarah Joe Ansi (with middle name "Joe")
- Martin David (no middle name)
- Scott Joe (no middle name)

I want to query for people who have their middle or last name started with search criteria. Here's how I search for employees with middle name started with
"joe" :

```
            query = From emp In db.Employees _
                    Where emp.LastName.StartsWith("joe") _
                    Select emp
```

How do I query for employees with family name(last part of the LastName) started with "joe"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' return employees where family name starts with "joe"
query = From emp In db.Employees _
        Where emp.LastName.Substring(emp.LastName.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1) _
                          .StartsWith("joe") _
        Select emp

' return employees where middle name or family name starts with "joe"
query = From emp In db.Employees _
        Where emp.LastName.StartsWith("joe") _
            OrElse emp.LastName.Contains(" joe") _
        Select emp
```

Comment: @LukeH, It's not an answer to question. i.e it returns `Mary Sample TestJoe` but it shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Saeed: No it does not! I suggest that you actually try it before downvoting.

Comment: It's easy to test it, your .Net will say you.

Comment: @Saeed: Your own answer is wrong, in fact. It doesn't match when the employee has no middle name. You're lucky that Matt and I aren't as free-and-easy with our downvotes as you are!

Comment: LukeH you are false, In all your answer is not an answer to `OP` op wants `How do I query for employees with family name(last part of the LastName) started with "joe"` not what you and @Matt do it, read the question carefully.

Comment: Read `last part of the LastName` carefully, my downvote is true for you and Matt.

Comment: @Saeed: I suggest that *you* need to read the question more carefully: *"Some people have middle name and some don't."* My answer -- and Matt's -- will match an employee called "fred joelson"; yours won't.

Comment: Your answer also Matchs `Mary Joe Johnson` and it shouldn't, and I think the `OP` wants to match last part, means if the last part exist else do not match anything, if else my answer is wrong like you and Matt.

Comment: @Saeed: You'll notice that there are two queries in my answer -- *with explanatory comments* -- because the question is slightly ambiguous. The first query won't match "mary joe johnson"; the second one will; the OP can choose which query best fits their needs.

Comment: OK, I just see the second one, edit your question to remove downvote. In all your first answer may be cause to exception.

Comment: @LukeH Is there a way to search in this manner for multiple words? I.e. where any of the words in `FullName` starts with any of the words in the search phrase?

Answer (score 3):

```
query = From emp In db.Employees _
   Where emp.LastName.StartsWith("joe") _
   or Lastname.contains(" joe") _
   Select emp
```

Comment: Solves the given problem, but what if the middle name was Mary Joe (Mary Joe Johnson)?  Middle name should be a separate field.

Comment: Yeah true I had not thourght of that. Agreed that the Middle name should be a separate field

Comment: @GenericTypeTea "want to query for people who have their middle or last name started with search criteria. "

Comment: @Matt - Arrr bugger. I've spent the last 5 minutes trying to solve totally the wrong problem. +1

Comment: @GenericTypeTea Sounds like me in so many of my exams I now read things 3-4 times :)

Comment: @Matt - Yeah, ditto. I always ended up giving awesome, in depth answers about totally the wrong thing when I did my GCSEs.

Comment: It's not an answer to question. for example it returns `Mary Sample TestJoe` but it shouldn't do this.

Comment: See my comment on Lukeh, your answer is not what the `OP` wants.